# How to edit datagridview columns which is filled from database? C# Windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have doing billing application with Windows Forms. I have there datagridview:
[Datagridview with colums](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UTOs.jpg)

And when I type number to first column (Tuotekoodi / product code in english), for example in picture I have typed number 1 to first column, and then it automatically fill "Nimike" and "á Hinta" columns from database.

So my problem is that I can't edit "Nimike" or "á Hinta" columns anymore. I can but when I move to next column it reads same values back to columns. So how I can edit values in  "Nimike" and "á Hinta" columns after it reads values from database to those columns?

And here is my codes where have cellValueChanged event:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.RowIndex == -1) return;

        DataGridViewTextBoxCell cb = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0];
        if (cb.Value != null)
        {

            con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT name, price FROM product where productID=@pid", con);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("pid", cb.Value.ToString());

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["productName"].Value = reader["name"];
                    dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["productPrice"].Value = reader["price"];
                }
            }

            con.Close();

        }  
    }
```

And CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event which makes changes to columns immediately when typed to first column.

```
private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
        {
            dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);   
        }
    }
```

Cheers

Teme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unsubscribe the function from the event after the code done for the first time to make the code runs only once. This will be like `Form1.DatagridView.CellValueChanged -=  dataGridView1_CellValueChanged;`